# populate values from one controller to another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, controller, populate

I have two types of controllers,

- JobController
- EmployerController

These two controllers, the details are below,

- Contactperson
- ContactNumber
- MobileNumber
- EmailAddress

These details are the same in both controllers. I kept all values separate. Now I want to populate the details from Employercontroller to Jobcontroller.

Here is how I populate all these details from organization to job. Any Idea? I already searched google for so many references.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple scenario to look at on the basis of details you have provided.

If you are having Two controllers then there should be separate repository calls to access data in those controller. But it seems that you need to persist the data in case of redircting to another action. If it is the case... then you can use Temp data to store the values and access those in another controller action like following..

Store values in TempData in your Employee controller

```
Organization organization = _userRepository.GetOrganizationById(LoggedInOrganization.Id);
            organization.ContactPerson = collection["ContactPerson"];
            organization.Email = collection["Email"];
            organization.Website = collection["Website"];
            organization.ContactNumber = collection["ContactNumber"];
            organization.MobileNumber = collection["MobileNumber"];
            TempData["Details"] = organization;
```

And then you can access it in another controller action after redirection..

```
var organisation = (Organisation) TempData["Details"];
job.ContactPerson = organisation.ConcactPerson;
                job.ContactNumber = organisation..ContactNumer;
                job.MobileNumber = organisation..MobileNumber;
                job.EmailAddress = organisation.Email;
```

**Remember :** Above code is usefull if you are assigning details on one action and redirecting to another action only.. Read about Tempdata on google.

If these two controllers have no relation in any context then it would be a good practice to acceess the data from repository and use it.

If you still have doubt or didn't satisfied with the answer, please put your issue in detail to address.

Cheers

Comment: i can't find the solution. i use same repository only.In jobcontroller i call organizationid. One organizationId can have multiple jobs...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `ViewData` or `TempData` to communicate between two controller actions. This article points out the difference between the two.

http://www.squaredroot.com/2007/12/20/mvc-viewdata-vs-tempdata/

The main difference is that `TempData` is really for communicating between 2 controllers.

> *Ben Scheirman*:
>   http://flux88.com/2008/01/testing-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc/, "TempData
>   is a session-backed temporary storage dictionary that is available for
>   one single request. It’s great to pass messages between controllers."

Answer (score 0):

just create a method DATA() in  controller "A" and create object of controller "A" in controller "B" and call the method DATA() whenever you want get data of particular variable.